# Existence of boolean function with exponential average case hardness

Tags: circuits, lower-bounds

Show that for every large enough $n$, there is a boolean function $f\colon \{0,1\}^n\longrightarrow\{0,1\}$, whose average case hardness is exponential. The question is taken from Arora Barak Computational Complexity textbook, Chapter-16, Ex-3.

Average case hardness of a boolean function $f$ is defined as, the largest $S(n)$ s.t. for all circuit $C_n\in \operatorname{Size}(S(n))$, $\Pr_{x\in U_n}[C_n(x)=f(x)]<1/2+1/S(n)$. Here $U_n$ is uniform distribution over $\{0,1\}^n$. I want to show there are boolean functions having $S(n)$ exponential in $n$. My approach is to pick a random $f$ and show via Chernoff bound, the probability of having such function is $>0$.

Formally, I am following this approach, I need to show, $\Pr_{x\in U_n}[C_n(x)=f(x)]-1/2<1/2^n$, $S(n)=2^n$ . Take $Y$ another random variable, $Y=1$ iff, $C_n[x]=f[x]$ else $0$. I express $\Pr_{x\in U_n}[C_n(x)=f(x)]=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum Y_i$,  Now, by Chernoff bound if I can bound the probability $\Pr[\frac{1}{2^n}\sum Y_i-1/2]>1/2^n$ over $C$, I can take the union bound over all $C$ to show that probability is less than $1$. But, I am not sure if I can replace $\mu$ of Chernoff bound with any constant like $1/2$.

Is my approach correct? Can anyone help with my query? $U_n$ is uniform distribution.

Comment: Can you state precisely what you are trying to show?

Comment: Using chernoff bound, I want to show that the probability of random $f$, having exponential average case hardness is $>0$, thus it exists, but that needs $\mu$ in chernoff bound to be replaced by $p$. I am not quite sure if I am following the correct approach here.

Comment: Can you state precisely what you are trying to show? I have no idea what you mean by "exponential average case hardness". Try to be explicit.

Comment: Average case hardness of a boolean function is defined as, the largest $S(n)$ s.t. for all circuit $C_n\in Size(S(n))$, $Pr_{x\in U_n}[C_n(x)=f(x)]<1/2+1/S(n)$. Here $U_n$ is uniform distribution over $\{0,1\}^n$. I want to show there are functions with exponential $S(n)$.

Comment: Instead of answering in the comments, please update your question. Don't add an "EDIT:" paragraph. Instead, just update the wording of your question to contain the necessary information.

Comment: You won't be able to show that any function has hardness $2^n$, since every function can be computed exactly using a circuit of size $O(2^n/n)$.

Comment: I want to prove there exists $f$ with hardness $2^n$. Any other approach?

Comment: You cannot prove it because it is false.

Comment: But this question is present in Arora Barak chapt 16 ex-3

Comment: I can think of exponential functions other than $2^n$...

Comment: Ok, I did not know that $2^n$ is not possible. But is my approach correct for other exponentials? Also my chernoff bound proof I do not know whether it is correct? Any suggestions?

Comment: If your approach could work for any exponential, then it necessarily fails. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes, my proof is independent of the exponential. If it fails, can you point to me to a better approach..

Comment: If you are answering a specific exercise, please credit the source of the exercise in the question and quote the statement of it.

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C$ be a fixed function, and let $f$ be a random function. For $z \in \{0,1\}^n$, let $X_z = 1$ if $C(z) = f(z)$, and $X_z = -1$ otherwise. Thus
$$
2^{-n} \sum_z X_z = \Pr[C(z) = f(z)] - \Pr[C(z) \neq f(z)] = 2\Pr[C(z) = f(z)] - 1.
$$
Therefore $\Pr[C(z) = f(z)] \geq 1/2+\delta$ iff $2^{-n} \sum_z X_z \geq 2\delta$. According to [Bernstein's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_inequalities_(probability_theory)),
$$
\Pr\left[2^{-n} \sum_z X_z \geq 2\delta\right] \leq \exp \left(-\frac{42^n\delta^2}{2(1+2\delta/3)}\right) \leq e^{-2^n\delta^2}.
$$
(The true exponent is more like $-2^{n+1}\delta^2$.)

The number of (de Morgan) circuits of size $s$ is at most roughly $e^{2s\log s}$ (according to notes of [Trevisan](https://cs.stanford.edu/%7Etrevisan/cs254-10/lecture03.pdf); the bound is not tight). According to the union bound, the probability (over $f$) that *some* circuit $C$ of size $s$ satisfies $\Pr[C(z) = f(z)] \geq 1/2+\delta$ is at most $e^{2s\log s} \cdot e^{-2^n\delta^2}$. If $2s\log s < 2^n\delta^2$ then this probability is less than $1$, and so there exists some function $f$ such that $\Pr[C(z) = f(z)] < 1/2+\delta$ for *all* circuits of size $s$.

You're interested in the setting $\delta = 1/s$. The argument works as long as $2s^3\log s < 2^n$, and in particular, when $s\approx2^{n/3}$.

Comment: $Pr[2^{-n}\sum_zX_z\geq2\delta]\leq e^{-2^n\delta^2}\leq 2^{-2^n\delta^2}$, so we can replace de morgan circuits with any boolean circuit where the number of circuits of size $S$ becomes $2^s(2+2log(S))$. This also works I think. Thanks for your help..

Comment: One doubt, what was wrong in my approach using chernoff bound?

Comment: Nothing wrong. All these bounds are the same. You just never carried your plan through.